# select best record possible

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Have different files in a directory as below

**f1.txt**

```
id FName Lname Adrress sex levelId

t1 Girish Hm 10oak m 1111 

t2 Kiran Kumar 5wren m 2222

t3 sara chauhan 15nvi f 6666
```

**f2.txt**

```
t4 girish hm 11oak m 1111 

t5 Kiran Kumar 5wren f 2222

t6 Prakash Jha 18nvi f 3333
```

**f3.txt**

```
t7 Kiran Kumar 5wren f 2222

t8 Girish Hm 10oak m 1111

t9 Prakash Jha 18nvi m 3333
```

**f4.txt**

```
t10 Kiran Kumar 5wren f 2222 

t11 girish hm 10oak m 1111

t12 Prakash Jha 18nvi f 3333
```

only first name and last name constant here and case should be ignored,
other Address,Sex, levelID could be changed.

Data should  be grouped first based on fname and lname

```
t1 Girish Hm 10oak m 1111 

t4 girish hm 11oak m 1111 

t8 Girish Hm 10oak m 1111

t11 girish hm 10oak m 1111



t2 Kiran Kumar 5wren m 2222

t5 Kiran Kumar 5wren f 2222

t7 Kiran Kumar 5wren f 2222

t10 Kiran Kumar 5wren f 2222 


t3 sara chauhan 15nvi f 6666



t6 Prakash Jha 18nvi f 3333

t9 Prakash Jha 18nvi m 3333

t12 Prakash Jha 18nvi f 33
```

Later we need to choose appropriate first record from each group based on frequency  of values of columns Address,Sex,LevelID

Example: For person Girish Hm

```
10oak has maximum frequency from address

m has maximum frequency from gender

1111 has maximum frequency from LevelID.
```

so, Id with t1 will be correct record(considering need to choose 1st appropriate record from the group)

Final output should be:

```
t1 Girish Hm 10oak m 1111

t5 Kiran Kumar 5wren f 2222

t3 sara chauhan 15nvi f 6666

t6 Prakash Jha 18nvi f 3333
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what specific problem are you running into?

Comment: I am able to group the data, But I am not getting further idea to get appropriate row from group based on frequency, Could you please help if I have any idea.

Comment: Could you show the code so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scala solution:

First define columns of interest:

```scala
val cols = Array("Adrress", "sex", "levelId")
```

Then add an array column of each column of interest and its frequency using

```scala
df.select(
    cols.map(
        x => array(
            count(x).over(
                Window.partitionBy(
                    lower(col("FName")),
                    lower(col("LName")),
                    col(x) 
                )
            ),
            col(x)
        ).alias(x ++ "_freq")
    )
)
```

Then group by each person and aggregate to get the maximum frequency: (ignore the dummy agg which is due to the agg function requiring an argument and a bunch of other arguments)

```
.groupBy(
    lower(col("FName")).alias("FName"),
    lower(col("LName")).alias("LName"))
.agg(
    count($"*").alias("dummy"),
    cols.map(
        x => max(col(x ++ "_freq"))(1).alias(x)
    ): _*
)
.drop("dummy"))
```

Overall code:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val cols = Array("Adrress", "sex", "levelId")

val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", " ").option("inferSchema", "true").csv("names.txt")

val df2 = (df
.select(col("*") +: cols.map(x => array(count(x).over(Window.partitionBy(lower(col("FName")), lower(col("LName")), col(x))), col(x)).alias(x ++ "_freq")): _*)
.groupBy(lower(col("FName")).alias("FName"), lower(col("LName")).alias("LName"))
.agg(count($"*").alias("dummy"), cols.map(x => max(col(x ++ "_freq"))(1).alias(x)): _*)
.drop("dummy"))

df2.show
+-------+-------+-------+---+-------+
|  FName|  LName|Adrress|sex|levelId|
+-------+-------+-------+---+-------+
|   sara|chauhan|  15nvi|  f|   6666|
|prakash|    jha|  18nvi|  f|   3333|
| girish|     hm|  10oak|  m|   1111|
|  kiran|  kumar|  5wren|  f|   2222|
+-------+-------+-------+---+-------+
```

Comment: Hi mck, Thanks for detailed solution, really appreciate it :)

Comment: Hi mck, Could please explain how max work on Array, Because array has two values here.

Comment: @GirishHM It will find max by sorting to the first key of array, which is the count